# How to change attribute with another attribute for mvc asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have one table called Article, with columns id int primary key, name varchar not null, department_id int not null. Also department_id is foreign key. I have table Department which has id int primary key, and DepartmentName varchar not null.

I created a web form which consist all columns of table Article. That is ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID. I want to put data for column DepartmentName instead of Department_ID. But also, some how to insert department_id.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: I've read this question three times, and it is not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make any sense at all. And why would you insert the DepartmentName to a second table. That violates normalization and will cause a lot of anguish.

Comment: Or maybe you just want to display the DepartmentName??? You would do that by joining the two tables together.

Comment: Anybody tell me where the hell DepartmentName appeared?

Comment: I don't know why everyone is complaining, I find the question clear.

Comment: @DanDumitru Then explain it to us, because it certainly isn't clear to the rest of us.

Comment: Please update your post to include the code / html for your web form.

Comment: @Amy - In a web page, he wants to display all the articles, and for each article the department name.

Comment: @DanDumitru how did you get that from "I want to put data for column DepartmentName instead of Department_ID. But also, some how to insert department_id."  IMO, you're guessing.

Comment: Hi @Nikola, your question is "I have web forms that allow the user to add a new Article and associate it to a department or create a new one if the department not exists."?

Comment: @Amy - He displays a list of articles (ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID). But, of course, he doesn't want to display the department id, he wants to display the department name there. His wording is a bit off, that I admit.

Comment: @DanDumitru since it is so clear to you I am looking forward to your answer because this is a giant mud pie to me. I can come up with at least three or four possibilities of what the OP is after.

Comment: @DanDumitru I agree that's a semi-reasonable interpretation, but there are other ways to interpret the question that are equally valid.  OP needs to edit his question for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, on my tenth re-reading of the question I realized he might as well be talking about an edit form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for the view could look something like this, guessing you're using models and select tag for displaying departments:

```
<select id="departmentDropDown">
   @foreach (var dpt in Department){
       <option value=@dpt.id>@dpt.DepartmentName</option>
   }
</select>
```

Or you could use something like :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department, listItems, "-- Select Department--")
```

But then you'd have to populate list of SelectListItems e.g `List<SelectListItem> listItems;` with all the departments and use that if you don't have that already prepared in the code.

Also there might be some syntax errors in the code I wrote here 'cos I'm writing it here immediately since I don't have time to check it out at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a  bit confuse, but i think i know what you want.

What you have to do is create a model to the view, called ViewModel.

For example, your ViewModel would be someting like this:

```
public class ArticleViewModel{
  public Article Article {get; set;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Departments {get; set;} // Source for the select
}
```

In your view, you will have something like this (this is mvc core):

```
@model Your.Namespace.ArticleViewModel

(...)

<form asp-action="Create">
  (...)
          <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Article.DEPARTMENT_ID" class="col-md-2 control-label">Department</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="Article.DEPARTMENT_ID" asp-items="Model.Departments" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected></option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Article.DEPARTMENT_ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  (...)
</form>
```

In the controller, in create (get), you will have something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(){
  List<Departments> departements = getDepartmentsFromDatabase();

  ArticleViewModel viewModel = new ArticleViewModel{
    Article = new Article(),
    Departments = departements.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.id.ToString(),
                    Text = x.DepartmentName
                }).ToList()
  }
  return View(viewModel);

}
```

In the controller, in create (post), you will have something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ArticleViewModel articleViewModel) {
       (...)
       saveTheModel(articleViewModel.Article);
       (...)
    }
```

This is not tested but the idea is here.
Hope this helps.

Comment: IT'S WORK. THANK YOU.

Comment: Nice. Mark as the answer.